# Explain, using examples, the purpose of the bin directory is my answer suitable for this question?

Tags: terminal

I have looked at similar questions which already have answers but still not entirely sure on the answer. In addition I don't won't to copy someone and thats it I want to understand the answer.

Here is my answer.

/bin Stands for binary. This folder contains base executables which are required for the system to function. Commands which are available in /bin folder is accessed by everyone and can run by every user. This folder contains basic commands such as cat and chmod.

Comment: This isn't really a *question*.  It's an uncertain answer.  But as [EightBitTony has posted](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/273135/135943), you should read up on the [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](http://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs/index.html).

Answer (score 2):

The [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](http://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs/index.html) describes all the standard filesystems.

> 3.4. /bin : Essential user command binaries (for use by all users)
>
> 3.4.1. Purpose
>
> /bin contains commands that may be used by both the system
>   administrator and by users, but which are required when no other
>   filesystems are mounted (e.g. in single user mode). It may also
>   contain commands which are used indirectly by scripts.

I believe the key element is that `/bin` should be available without any other filesystems being mounted.